# why doesn't reshape() in MATLAB give me the same output as matrix() in R?

Tags: r, matlab

The first code is in R:

```
 > matrix(1:6,nrow=3,byrow=T)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    3    4
 [3,]    5    6
```

The second code is in MATLAB:

```
>> reshape(1:6,3,2)'
ans =

    1     2     3
    4     5     6
```

Comment: Is the question about the matlab or the R output?

Comment: Why do you expect the same output?

Comment: The question is about matlab. I read a reference that says both codes will give same output but when i tried them the above was the output. I want to reshape a 3x2 matrix in matlab by rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB matrices are stored column-wise. What your `reshape` does is take a row vector of `1:6`, and start filling out a new 3-by-2 matrix *column-wise*:

```
1    4
2    5
3    6
```

The apostrophe after the reshape transposes this to produce:

```
1     2     3
4     5     6
```

To obtain what you actually want, create a 2-by-3 matrix using `reshape` first, then transpose it.

```
reshape(1:6, 2, 3)'
```

Comment: I believe this should be: `reshape(1:6,2,3)'`? Transposing after `reshape`, to get the same result as the R-code. `[1 2;3 4;5 6]`, that is.

Comment: @RobertP, Oops, haven't noticed it. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: transpose before and after will give the same output. This isnt what i want i want the output in matlab to be like the output in r. i.e reshape matrix by row not by column.

Comment: "In MATLAB matrices are stored column-wise"; also true for R, which the OP however bypasses with the `byrow=T` :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're transposing a 3x2 matrix in MATLAB, which you don't do in R:

```
>> reshape(1:6,3,2)  % NOTE: no apostrophe at the end
ans =
   1     4
   2     5
   3     6
```

Second, you are filling by *row* in R, which is different from the default (and also different from how MATLAB does it);

```
> matrix(1:6,nrow=3,byrow=F)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5   # yay, results agree!
[3,]    3    6
```

If you want to fill by row in MATLAB, you'll have to reverse the arguments and transpose:

```
>> reshape(1:6, 2,3).'  % NOTE: arguments for row and column counts reversed
ans =
    1     2
    3     4
    5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is, that you want do the command by rows ... imho this isn't possible in Matlab. So you need a little workaround

```
reshape(1:6,2,3)
```

give you

```
1   3   5
2   4   6
```

Transposing all this.

```
reshape(1:6,2,3)'
```

gives you this result:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

For more detail see
[Doku reshape](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you the output you are looking for:

```
reshape(1:6, 2, 3)'
```